How to do a net tie between one copper pours?
I am currently working on a project where I need to power different banks of FPGA with the same buck converter. To distinguish between the banks in the FPGA, I am using a Net Tie for separation, which makes it easier for me to place decaps under the BGA. However, I have encountered an issue with the Net Tie: the polygon pour or trace is not recognizing both nets as the same.




That's because it's two different nets, as it is two different names. Why do you need to connect the FPGA power bank to two nets with different names, but which are the same? If it's just your layout of decoupling caps, then I'm afraid the easiest solution is to pay attention to the ref des of the caps to make sure you place the right ones in the right place.

If you have grouped the caps nicely in your schematic you can just select them there and move the selected group of components in the pcb editor to the relevant routing area.

This is, in fact, a major reason net ties are used in the first place. The point of a net tie is to be a single-point connection between two nets.

@Puffafish When dealing with multiple banks of FPGAs powered by let say a common 3.3V rail, it can be challenging to identify which pins belong to each bank during layout. This ambiguity complicates the placement of decoupling capacitors to ensure effective decoupling for all banks.
